# remove child node namespace and copy another node into a variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to copy all the child elements of soap:Header element into a variable and also trying to remove PricingRequest empty namespace (xmlns="http://www.ama.net") and output only PricingRequest part of xml. I am able to remove PricingRequest empty namespace and get proper output but not able to store soap:Header child elements into a variable, is it  possible to copy child elements of soap:Header into a variable ?

INPUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap ="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header xmlns="http://www.ama.net/1axml-msg/schema/msg-header-1_0.xsd">
  <MessageHeader ResponseRequested="true" version="1.0" Terminate="true" Reverse="true" id="09B5581A" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
    <From>1ASI</From>
    <To>1ASRINSAIG</To>
    <TimeStamp>
      <GenerationTime>2014-10-22T12:41:38Z</GenerationTime>
    </TimeStamp>    
  </MessageHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<PricingRequest xmlns="http://www.ama.net">
    <originatorSection>
        <deliverySystem>
            <companyId>1A</companyId>
            <cityCode>MUC</cityCode>
        </deliverySystem>       
    </originatorSection>    
</PricingRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.ama.net" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!--    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='Envelope']">
        <xsl:variable name="SOAPHeader" select="/soap:Header/node()" />
        <xsl:text> MessageHeader INFO:<xsl:copy-of select="$SOAPHeader"/>  </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>  -->

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>      
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(ancestor-or-self::x:PricingRequest)]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

getting expecting OUTPUT but not able to copy soap:Header into a variable:

```
<PricingRequest>
  <originatorSection>
    <deliverySystem>
      <companyId>1A</companyId>
      <cityCode>MUC</cityCode>
    </deliverySystem>
  </originatorSection>
</PricingRequest>
```

Comment: You say "*copy child elements of soap:Header*" but you're showing the descendants of soap:Body.

Comment: hi Michael, thanks for looking into my question. The above xslt is able to get the output XML what i am looking for and for logging purpose, i need to print all elements and attributes inside soap:Header. if you look at my xslt, you can see what i am trying to do in commented code. I am not able to match soap:Header and copy its content into a variable

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="SOAPHeader" select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/node()" />
    <xsl:text>MessageHeader INFO:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$SOAPHeader"/>  
</xsl:template>
```

**Note**:

1. `<xsl:text>` cannot contain child elements;
2. your version has conflicting templates for `soap:Envelope`.

Comment: I Michael, thanks for information on xsl:text , i used your code and re-framed my initial question. i am trying to transform to a new XML without namespaces, is it possible to do that ?

Comment: @sarma I suggest you roll back your question to the original and post a new one (after closing this one).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i rolled back to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

the following code worked the way i wanted. I am able to copy soap:Header child elements in a variable and also removed PricingRequest namespace in the output

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.ama.net/1axml-msg/schema/msg-header-1_0.xsd"
    xmlns:ns2="http://www.ama.net" exclude-result-prefixes="ns1 ns2 soap">

    <xsl:template match="ns1:* | ns2:*| soap:*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="SOAPHeader">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/node()" />          
        </xsl:variable>         
        <xsl:text>HeaderInfo:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$SOAPHeader" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/node()" />    
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT I am getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
HeaderInfo:
  <MessageHeader xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ResponseRequested="true" version="1.0" Terminate="true" Reverse="true" id="09B5581A" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
    <From>1ASI</From>
    <To>1ASRINSAIG</To>
    <TimeStamp>
      <GenerationTime>2014-10-22T12:41:38Z</GenerationTime>
    </TimeStamp>    
  </MessageHeader>

<PricingRequest>
    <originatorSection>
        <deliverySystem>
            <companyId>1A</companyId>
            <cityCode>MUC</cityCode>
        </deliverySystem>       
    </originatorSection>    
</PricingRequest>
```